# Change margin on click then revert on second click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a simple slide animation to convert from 'mouseenter'/'mouseleave' on larger screens to a 'click' function on smaller screen but cant quite get it right.

The idea being there is a hidden div with negative left margin (-220px) that slides in on 'mouseenter' or 'click' to 0 margin while pushing the current div out the way on 'mouseleave' with a (+220px left-margin). It works fine on 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' and on the first 'click' but i want it to revert back on second click to the default state like it does on 'mouseleave'

```js
 $('#mouseenter').mouseenter(function () {
      $('#mouseenter .box-heading').css('margin-left', '220px');
      $('#mouseenter .box-hidden-info').css('margin-left', '0');
    });

    $('#mouseenter').mouseleave(function () {
      $('#mouseenter .box-heading').css('margin-left', '0');
      $('#mouseenter .box-hidden-info').css('margin-left', '-220px');
    });

$('#click').click(function () {
      $('#click .box-heading').css('margin-left', '220px');
      $('#click .box-hidden-info').css('margin-left', '0');
    });
```

```css
.box {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-heading {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.box-hidden-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
  margin-left: -220px;
}

.box-hidden-info p {
  font-size: 72%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 120%;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" id="mouseenter">
                  <div class="box-heading">
                    <h1>Mouseenter</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-hidden-info">
                    <p>Test text test text</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

 <div class="box" id="click">
                  <div class="box-heading">
                    <h1>click</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-hidden-info">
                    <p>Test text test text</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: toggle a class.... don't set the values with JavaScript....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function instead of `.click()`

```js
$('#mouseenter').mouseenter(function () 
{
    $('#mouseenter .box-heading').css('margin-left', '220px');
    $('#mouseenter .box-hidden-info').css('margin-left', '0');
});

$('#mouseenter').mouseleave(function () 
{
    $('#mouseenter .box-heading').css('margin-left', '0');
    $('#mouseenter .box-hidden-info').css('margin-left', '-220px');
});

$('#click').click(function () 
{ 
    $('#click .box-heading').toggleClass("addLeftMargin");
    $('#click .box-hidden-info').toggleClass("addLeftMargin");
});
```

```css
.addLeftMargin
{
  margin-left: 220px;
}

.box {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-heading {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.box-hidden-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
  margin-left: -220px;
}

.box-hidden-info p {
  font-size: 72%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 120%;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" id="mouseenter">
    <div class="box-heading">
      <h1>Mouseenter</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box-hidden-info">
      <p>Test text test text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="click">
    <div class="box-heading">
      <h1>click</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box-hidden-info">
      <p>Test text test text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks for this much appreciated, for some strange reason it doesn't seem to be working. It just seems to be setting both .box-heading and box-hidden-info to display none and they don't seem to appear when clicked.

Comment: works perfect now thanks very much again for your kind help

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the entire `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` function with CSS `:hover`

```
#mouseenter:hover .box-heading {
  margin-left: 220px;
}
#mouseenter:hover .box-hidden-info {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

For the click part, you should use `toggleClass()`, on the element itself, like this:

```
$('#click').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('click');
});
```

Then in your CSS, style how the child elements of `#click` should look like when the parent has the class `.click` added to it.

To spare some code, you can just modify the `:hover` CSS part, so it also includes the `.click` state:

```
#mouseenter:hover .box-heading,
#click.click .box-heading {
  margin-left: 220px;
}
#mouseenter:hover .box-hidden-info,
#click.click .box-hidden-info{
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

**Full Code:**

```js
$('#click').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('click');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-heading {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.box-hidden-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
  margin-left: -220px;
}

#mouseenter:hover .box-heading,
#click.click .box-heading {
  margin-left: 220px;
}
#mouseenter:hover .box-hidden-info,
#click.click .box-hidden-info{
  margin-left: 0;
}

.box-hidden-info p {
  font-size: 72%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 120%;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="mouseenter">
  <div class="box-heading">
    <h1>Mouseenter</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box-hidden-info">
    <p>Test text test text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="click">
  <div class="box-heading">
    <h1>click</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box-hidden-info">
    <p>Test text test text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks for this will give it a go for sure. The only reason i used mouseenter/leave over css was purely because i wanted to convert this to click on smaller devices and i thought using hover in css would cause issues when it comes to clicking if you see what i mean. Your suggestion looks great though so will try it for sure. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `toggle` function to have another behavior on alternate click

```
$('#click').toggle(function () {
  //move right
}, function () {
  //move left
});
```

More details here https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: **Remarks from JQuery**: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9.